# What is the best way to specify constraints containing multiplication of two variables in SCIP?

Tags: scip

I am using SCIP Optimization Suite 3.0.2 to in my c++ code to implement a scheduler and I would like to ask you what is the best way to implement constraint such as:

`t_i*p + d*p + t_i <=0`

where `t_i` is a continous variable, `p` is a binary variable, `d` is a constant. I found the overview of all supported type of constraints: [scip constraints](http://scip.zib.de/doc-3.0.2/html/group__CONSHDLRS.shtml) and I somehow implemented my problem as a hierarchy of more linear constraints and conjunctions and disjunctions between them, but I have a suspicious that makes the search for a solution hard. Thus, I am interested if there is some more straightforward way, especially for multiplying of two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can formulate this as a quadratic constraint.  See the "Callable library" example,

http://scip.zib.de/doc/examples/CallableLibrary/

in particalur the file string.c, for an example of how to implement this using the callable library, and the general documentation

http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/cons__quadratic_8h.php#ad3707e7f7166bea83b7713cf2e52b0db

Have fun,
ambros

Comment: Welcome to SO! Even though you included the URLs, it's much helpful to add the parts, which are important for this particular question.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the constraint that you mentioned, there even is a linear formulation, at least if `t_i` is bounded to be nonnegative:
Since `p` is supposed to be binary, it breaks down to either

- `p = 0` => `t_i` <= 0, forcing `t_i` to 0 because of nonnegativity assumed above
- `p = 1` => 2 * `t_i` <= -`d`

You can fold this into a single linear constraint, in which `p` is basically imposing an upper bound on `t_i`:

```
t_i + d / 2 * p <= 0
```

Using SCIP's callable library, you can directly create this constraint as a [varbound](http://scip.zib.de/doc-3.0.2/html/cons__varbound_8h.shtml) constraint.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I used more general case, but I simplified it to my question. So I was really interested in quadratic constraints.